# Why is the listbox selection not working when the AfterUpdate() event of a combobox is fired?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Whenever I click on another combo box's dropdown button from the current combo box and select an item from the dropdown list, the combo box field will appear blank and I have to re-click the dropdown list and select the item in order to get the value into the combo box field.

However, when I click on the combo box field first prior to clicking on the dropdown of that combo box, selecting an item from the list will immediately place the value of the selected item into the combo box.

The code of the combo box is shown below:

```
Private Sub cbxSupplier_AfterUpdate()
Dim Supplier_col As Long

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Box").ListObjects("tblFoilInfoHelper").DataBodyRange.ClearContents
Set filteredRangeFoilProfile = Nothing
lbxFoilInfoDisplay.RowSource = vbNullString
Supplier_col = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").ListColumns("SUPPLIER").Index

If Len(Trim(cbxSupplier)) = 0 Then
    filterRangeFoilProfile.AutoFilter Field:=Supplier_col
Else
    filterRangeFoilProfile.AutoFilter Field:=Supplier_col, Criteria1:=cbxSupplier.Text
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set filteredRangeFoilProfile = Intersect(filterRangeFoilProfile, filterRangeFoilProfile.Offset(1, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not filteredRangeFoilProfile Is Nothing Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foil Profile").ListObjects("tblFoilProfile").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Box").Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial
    lbxFoilInfoDisplay.RowSource = "List_Box!A2:" & Col_Letter(TotalColumnsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box")) & TotalRowsCount("Foil Purchases.xlsm", "List_Box", "tblFoilInfoHelper")
    Call Dynamic_cbx
End If

End Sub
```

I believe the `Call Dynamic_cbx` module is not the cause of it because I commented it out and the issue is still the same.

Comment: Can you add a Breakpoint at the start of the Sub, to see if the Event is being called or not?  If so, stepping through with F8 should help you work out which line is causing the issue

Comment: @Chronocidal sadly during the stepping through I cannot select anything from the listbox. Once I finish stepping the entire code within the `AfterUpdate()` event, it returns the same issue.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of the code, *then* select something from the listbox.  If the Event is triggering, then it will immediately step into the code and stop at the breakpoint for you to step through.

Comment: The event triggers with no errors and I was able to step through after the breakpoint but I cannot select anything from the dropdown while stepping through sadly. Only after the event ended

Comment: I currently can't recreate the error from your description - however, does adding `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Box").Column(1).Calculate` after the `PasteSpecial` force it to update OK?